# Is Junk Email auto scheduled for deletion in Outlook 2007?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, spam-prevention

Does Outlook 2007 automatically delete Junk email at scheduled intervals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is "No" to "scheduled".

If you are in a Microsoft Exchange environment, you could set up a rule to delete it automatically, or in stand-alone Outlook, you can have it deleted it before it goes to the folder, by checking "Permanently delete suspected junk e-mail instead of moving it to the Junk E-mail folder."

[image]

Comment: Thanks dude.  You've answered some of my questions before.  You must be smart.

Comment: @Steve Thank you for the compliment, and for marking the answer. I appreciate it.